Getting st_read("test_excel.xslx") to read in the whole file
Once again I am doing very basic operation with DuckDB. I want to create a table in duckdb based on an xlsx excel sheet. So far so good except for one minor detail. It seems to only have imported 1k rows out of 40k based on
 select count(*) from imported_table

How do I load and read in the whole table? Did I look at documentation. Yes I did. Did I see anything about this. No I did not.

Does the speadsheet file perhaps have more than one "layer"?

Yes, maybe that was it. Actually I think the file itself did not have the 40k rows that I though it did.
